# HTML or Javascript Decompiler Available

Tags: html

Is there any HTML or Javascript decompiler available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is not, since it's not compiled in the first place...is a javascript [unpacker or un-minifier](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/dec/go) what you are after?  If not, **right click** (or view menu), **view source**.

Also, [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) has built-in tools for this and [Firefox has Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), right click, inspect element in either.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + U :D 
On a serious note HTML and JS are not compiled as such , the code is generally open for all to see

Answer (score 1):

I just came up on this question from Google and decided to put in my two cents as things have changed.

You can use the [Spidermonkey Javasccript shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell). From this shell, you can actually disassemble script and view interpreter bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JS Beautifier DOT org](http://jsbeautifier.org/)
It's unpack and deofuscate any JS

or this [JS Beauty](http://labs.swelen.com/tools/javascript/beauty.html)

Answer (score -1):

In your browser, go to **View->Source** (short-cut **Cntr+U** in some browsers). Everything is there in front of you.